# How to make specific category bolder?

Tags: css, categories

I am using `the_category(', ');` function.

I want to make two specific category appear in bold like **category1**, **category2**, category3,category4.
Please help me how to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: As this is a CSS question, it would be helpful to share with us the HTML output of the function (and the corresponding css if exists) :)

Comment: some code would definitely help...

Comment: (Assuming you are referring to wordpress here ?)
What do you mean by specific category? Like you know the names of the category to which you want to apply the style or something like the 1st two categories as bold ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming you are referring to Wordpress here)

`the_category()` generates HTML with links to the categories as

```
<a href=".." title=".." rel="category">Category Name</a>
```

This can be used to target specific elements using jQuery :

```
$('a[rel=category]').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == 'your_category') {
        $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
    }
});
```

If you want to be more specific, you can wrap `the_category()` around a `div` :

```
<div id="categories">
    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
</div>
```

And then use `$('#categories a[rel=category]')` as the selector.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what i need. :) Thanks Nikhil Patel!

Comment: You're welcome :) (And you need to select the answer which helped you :D )

Comment: @HussainAnsari  here mark the answer if you got the correct answer for your question.